# How does QGIS Topology Checker check the topology of SHP and OSM files?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, openstreetmap, qgis-plugins

1. Can anybody make me clear if .shp & .osm (OpenStreetMap Data) are holding topological data/relations or not.
2. if .shp files are not holding then how qgis plugin topology checker checks for the topology of these files.

Comment: Welcome to gis.SE. This question isn't all that clear. Can you explain what you are "getting at"? For example, there is information about topology, but it isn't necessarily represented directly. Perhaps if you can explain what you are trying to achieve, what tools you intend to apply (e.g. what does openjump have to do with this?) and what the intended goal is, perhaps we can provide a more useful response. You can edit your question (just click the edit link below the question) to add these details, and anything else you can think of that might help (e.g. what you've already looked at).

Answer (score 2):

The QGIS topology checker checks the topology of the layer against rules specified by the user as per the [documentation](http://www.qgis.org/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_topology_checker.html).  Therefore the vector layer itself does not need to contain topology rules like an ESRI geodatabase.  Topology checker can check the topology of one layer against another one.

QGIS has a second tool for checking topology/geometry. Vector->Geometry Tools->Check Geometry Validity tool looks for violations of the OGR simple features specification within one layer.  Again, the vector data does not need to contain the rules as the topology check is against a predefined standard.